# How to remove a tooltip in wxpython?

Tags: python-2.7, wxpython, wxwidgets

How do I remove a tooltip in wxpython? I know they have an expiry time after which they disappear but I'm struggling to find anything in the docs about purposefully removing them.

In my particular situation, I have a wx.grid which on wx.EVT_MOTION calls a function, that gets the coordinates of the event in the grid, finds out which cell it is (a la grid.CalcUnscrolledPosition() and grid.XYToCell()) and then, provided it is a particular cell, creates a tooltip. Now, in the case there is a tooltip already, I want to remove it if the cursor hovers above a cell that doesn't require a tooltip. I'm struggling to find anything in the documentation. [This link](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.ToolTip-class.html) has the ToolTip.Enable() function, but that has no result whatsoever. The docs seem to imply that it should enable/disable tooltips globally but nothing happens.

Any ideas?

FYI, Win7, Python 2.7.9, wx 3.0.2.0

EDIT
Rough structure of relevant code:

```
self.grid.GetGridWindow().Bind(wx.EVT_MOTION, self.onMouseOver)

...

def onMouseOver(self, event):
    #get current grid cell
    x, y = self.grid.CalcUnscrolledPosition(event.GetX(), event.GetY())
    coords = self.grid.XYToCell(x,y)
    row = coords[0]
    col = coords[1]

    if col in relevanCols:
        event.GetEventObject().SetToolTipString("Hai")
    else:
        self.grid.SetToolTip(None)

    event.Skip()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, after beasting the damned thing for an age, a result and mind bogglingly simple as well `SetToolTip(None)`
See below:

```
import wx
class MyForm(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, "Toggle")
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY)
        self.dummy = wx.StaticText(self.panel, -1, "")
        self.cb1 = wx.CheckBox(self.panel, -1,"Choice 1", pos=(10,10))
        self.cb2 = wx.CheckBox(self.panel, -1,"Choice 2", pos=(10,40))
        self.cb1.Bind(wx.EVT_CHECKBOX, self.onToggle1)
        self.cb2.Bind(wx.EVT_CHECKBOX, self.onToggle2)
        self.cb1.SetToolTipString(wx.EmptyString)
        self.cb2.SetToolTipString(wx.EmptyString)
    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def onToggle1(self, event):
        if self.cb1.GetValue() == True:
            self.cb1.SetToolTipString("Check Box 1 is Checked")
        else:
            self.cb1.SetToolTip(None)

    def onToggle2(self, event):
        if self.cb2.GetValue() == True:
            self.cb2.SetToolTipString("Check Box 2 Is Checked")
        else:
            self.cb2.SetToolTip(None)

# Run the program
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MyForm()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Edit:
For the code in your question in relation to use in a grid, change the

```
if col in relevanCols:
    event.GetEventObject().SetToolTipString("Hai")
else:
    self.grid.SetToolTip(None)
```

to:

```
if col in relevanCols:
    event.GetEventObject().SetToolTipString("Hai")
else:
    event.GetEventObject().SetToolTip(None)
```

Comment: Unfortunately SetToolTip(None) doesn't work for me. My tooltips are in a wx.grid, rather than a checkbox and so it disappears only when the cursor leaves the grid. When I move to a different cell (one that shouldn't generate a new tooltip), current tooltip remains until expiry. I've added a stripped down version of my code to my question.

Comment: I haven't got time to mock it up now but have you tried `event.GetEventObject().SetToolTip(None)` rather than `self.grid.SetToolTip(None)`

Comment: Arghh, that's the one combination I hadn't tried and it worked! Thanks. Add it to your answer and I'll accept it. Thanks, man.

Comment: @kbau Arghh indeed. It happens to us all. The hours that we waste and then it's the bleeding obvious. It took your question for me to come back to this and solve it for myself, so thanks for the question. Answer edited.